# Kafka listener isn't listening to Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm using Java 11 and kafka-client 2.0.0.

I'm using the following code to generate a consumer :

```
    public Consumer createConsumer(Properties properties,String regex) {
        log.info("Creating consumer and listener..");
        Consumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
        ConsumerRebalanceListener listener = new ConsumerRebalanceListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                log.info("The following partitions were revoked from consumer : {}", Arrays.toString(partitions.toArray()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
                log.info("The following partitions were assigned to consumer : {}", Arrays.toString(partitions.toArray()));
            }
        };
        consumer.subscribe(Pattern.compile(regex), listener);
        log.info("consumer subscribed");
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

My poll loop is in a different place in the code :

```
public <K, V> void startWorking(Consumer<K, V> consumer) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<K, V> records = consumer.poll(600);
                if (records.count() > 0) {
                    log.info("Polled {} records", records.count());

                } else {
                    log.info("polled 0 records.. going to sleep..");
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                }
            }
        } catch (WakeupException | InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Consumer is shutting down", e);
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
        }
    }
```

When I run the code and use this function, the consumer is created and the log contains the following messages :

```
    Creating consumer and listener..
    consumer subscribed
polled 0 records.. going to sleep..
polled 0 records.. going to sleep..
polled 0 records.. going to sleep..
```

The log doesn't contain any info regarding the partition assignment/revocation.

In addition I'm able to see in the log the properties that the consumer uses (group.id is set) :

```
2020-07-09 14:31:07.959 DEBUG 7342 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [server1:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.id =
        group.id=mygroupid
        key.deserializer=..
        value.deserializer=..
```

So I tried to use the kafka-console-consumer with the same configuration in order to consume from one of the topics that the regex(mytopic.*) should catch (in this case I used the topic mytopic-1) :

```
/usr/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server server1:9092 --topic mytopic-1 --property print.timestamp=true --consumer.config /data/scripts/kafka-consumer.properties  --from-begining
```

I have a poll loop in other part of my code that is timing out every 10m .So the bottom line - the problem is that partitions aren't assigned to the Java consumer. The prints inside the listener never happen and the consumer doesn't have any partitions to listen to.

Comment: Hi JeyJ. Could I trouble you to use an English spell-checker please? Posts on Stack Overflow are intended to be for the benefit of future readers for many years, and thus we would rather they were as readable as possible. I appreciate you post merely to get a solution to your problem, but perhaps you can think of readability as an inexpensive "price" to post here.

Comment: Quite a lot of your prior posts have been amended for spelling, and there is an expectation here that when edit notifications are seen by content owners, a mental note is taken of the improvements that should be made going forward.

Comment: @halfer sure, I can do that. I dont think that my english is that poor, maybe a missing letter or something like that... I'm also trying always to leave an answer if I found a solution even if no one answered the question So you cant say that I'm not thinking about future readers..

Comment: Yes, apostrophes are particularly the issue. They will still flag up as misspellings (except, unfortunately, "wont" and "cant", which are words that have entirely unintended English meanings when the apostrophe is omitted). If you can take specific care over these sorts of words, that would be great.

Comment: @halfer will do in my next post/asnwer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was missing the ssl property in my properties file. Don't forget to specify the `security.protocol=ssl` if you use `ssl`. It seems that kafka-client API doesn't throw exception if the Kafka uses `ssl` and you try to access it without `ssl` parameter configured.